# Show that there is a real number $a$ such that $\Vert y-ax \Vert=\inf \{ \Vert y-bx \Vert: b\in\Bbb R\}$

Tags: functional-analysis

**Exercise:**

> $X$ is a normed linear space and $\Vert \quad \Vert$ is a norm on $X$. $x$ is a non-zero element in $X$. Then for all $y\in X$, there is a real number $a$ such that $\Vert y-ax \Vert=\inf \{ \Vert y-bx \Vert: b\in\Bbb R\}$.

**My Attempt**

I tried to work it out but failed. I haven't a clue about it.

**Added:**

Sorry for my hollow description.

It's clear that there is a lower bound for $\{ \Vert y-bx \Vert: b\in\Bbb R\}$ because $\Vert \quad \Vert$ is a norm and 0 is always a lower bound for the set.
So the set of real numbers $\{ \Vert y-bx \Vert: b\in\Bbb R\}$ does have a infimum.

Denote the infimum of this set by $l$.
Then for all $\varepsilon>0$, there is a real number $b$ such that $\Vert y-bx \Vert<l+\varepsilon$.
Namely, we can get a sequence $\{b_n\}_n$ such that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \Vert y-b_n x \Vert=l$.
Here, if $\{b_n\}_n$ converge to $a$, then we have $\Vert y-ax \Vert=\inf \{ \Vert y-bx \Vert: b\in\Bbb R\}$.
But how can I find a convergent $b_n$?

And in fact I'm not sure if my attempt is on a correct way.

Comment: [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391/quick-beginner-guide-for-asking-a-well-received-question) + please [avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933): edit your post to **show *explicitely* your attempts**, even if they failed. Hint: what can you say about the map $\Bbb R\to\Bbb R,\;t\mapsto\|y-tx\|$? (regularity, limit at $\pm\infty$)

Comment: Apologies: when I made a formatting change, I forgot to untick the default claim the closure reason is thereby addressed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the sequence $\{\|y-b_nx\|\}$, because it's convergent, is bounded. Let's say $L\in \Bbb R$ is such that $\|y-b_nx\|<L$ for all $n$.

The triangle inequality yields
$$
\big|\,\|bx\| - \|y\|\,\big| \leq \|y-bx\|
$$
Now set
$$
M = \frac{\|y\| + L}{\|x\|}
$$
The sequence $\{b_n\}$ is bounded (above and below) by this $M$. Indeed, $M<|b|$ yields
$$
\frac{\|y\| + L}{\|x\|}<|b|\\
L < |b|\cdot \|x\| - \|y\| \leq \|y-bx\|
$$
so this $b$ cannot be an element of the sequence $\{b_n\}$.

Thus $\{b_n\}$ has at least one convergent subsequence by compactness of the interval $[-M, M]$. Setting $a$ to be the limit of one of these subsequences lets you use the continuity of the function $b\mapsto\|y-bx\|$ to conclude.

Comment: Of course, it turns out that the function $b\mapsto \|y-bx\|$ is unimodal, so $\{b_n\}$ itself must be one of these convergent subsequences. But that's not a part of this problem.